# Magento - Better way to get block attribute value from xml

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Set data:

```
<block type="obishomeaddon/customcategory" name="customcategory" template="homeaddon/customcategory.phtml">
        <action method="setData"> <name>column_count</name> <value>4</value> </action>
        <action method="setData"> <name>category_id</name> <value>116</value> </action>
      </block>
```

Get data:

```
class Block extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
   public getColumnCount() { 
     return $this->getData('column_count');
   }

   public getCategoryId() { 
     return $this->getData('category_id');
   }
}
```

But I see Magento can do something like this :

```
<block type="obishomeaddon/customcategory" column_count="4" category_id="116" name="customcategory" template="homeaddon/customcategory.phtml"/>
```

How can I set the attribute value from this kind of setting data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock()` (the class responsible for generating the blocks), you will see that it is not possible to do this. However, it would be quite simple to add it in. You could override `Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock()` like this:

In your `config.xml` file:

```
<models>
    <core>
        <rewrite>
            <layout>Namespace_Module_Model_Core_Layout</layout>
        </rewrite>
    </core>
</models>
```

Then, in your file:

```
<?php

class Namespace_Module_Model_Core_Layout extends Mage_Core_Model_Layout
{
    protected function _generateBlock($node, $parent)
    {
        parent::_generateBlock($node, $parent);
        //   Since we don't want to rewrite the entire code block for 
        //   future upgradeability, we will find the block ourselves.

        $blockName = $node['name'];

        $block = $this->getBlock($blockName);
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Block_Abstract) {

            // We could just do $block->addData($node), but the following is a bit safer
            foreach ($node as $attributeName => $attributeValue) {
                if (!$block->getData($attributeName)) {
                    // just to make sure that we aren't doing any damage here.                    
                    $block->addData($attributeName, $attributeValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One other thing that you could do, without rewriting, to shorten up your XML is this:

```
<block type="obishomeaddon/customcategory" name="customcategory" template="homeaddon/customcategory.phtml">
    <action method="addData"><data><column_count>4</column_count> <category_id>116</category_id></data></action>
</block>
```